# How to change row background color based on date of cell, google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a form that people fill out, that goes to a google spreadsheet. When this happens, I am trying to automatically change the color of the new row from the form based upon the date in one of the columns. I have found questions similar to this, and I was able to generate this code from those questions, but when the code runs, it does not change the background color. What am I doing wrong?

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e) { 
    var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = e.source.getActiveRange(); 

    if (ss.getName() == "Form Responses Sorted") {

        // E.g. date column is 5th (E)
        date = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),5).getValue();


        rowRange = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),1,1,20);

        // This changes background color
        if (date == '8/5/2013') {
            rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#D00000");
        } else if (date == '8/12/2013') {
            rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#A0A0A0");
        } else if (date == '9/9/2013') { 
            rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#00FF00");
        } else if (date == '9/23/2013') {
            rowRange.setFontColor("#33FFCC");
        } else if (date == '9/30/2013') { 
            rowRange.setFontColor("#CCFF33");
        } else if (date == '10/7/2013') {
            rowRange.setFontColor("#FF6699");
        } else if (date == '10/21/2013') { 
            rowRange.setFontColor("#CC66CC");
        } else if (date == '11/4/2013') {
            rowRange.setFontColor("#6666FF");
        } else if (date == '11/25/2013') { 
            rowRange.setFontColor("#9933FF");
        } else if (date == '12/9/2013') {
            rowRange.setFontColor("#FF9933");
        } else if (date == '12/16/2013') { 
            rowRange.setFontColor("#FFFFFF");
        } else if (date == '1/13/2014') {
            rowRange.setFontColor("#CC9933");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: To clarify some points: Are you using Google Forms, right?,  in that case, you want to change the background color of the row you just sent from the Google Form? Is the date a form field, right (column 5)? If all this is true, check the event **Spreadsheet Form Submit** in [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events)

Comment: If any of the wchiquito points are no, can you add Logger.log(date) below the line date = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),5).getValue(); run the code then goto View - Logs and let me know the value you see there...

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely dealing with inconsistent data types in your comparisons. Let's just look at:

```
 if (date == '8/5/2013')
```

The default behavior in Google Sheets would be to convert a cell value of '8/5/2013' to a date, in the spreadsheet. Therefore, when you `getValue()`, you will have a javascript date object instance for the left side of this comparison.

What about the right side? It's a String, a primitive type in javascript. To compare these two types, one of them will be *coerced* so that we can compare them. Since the right is a primitive type, the left will be converted to match; a string. Let's see what that would be.

```
var A = String(date);   // Mon Aug 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

So, now you have a string comparison, which returns `false` because:

```
'Mon Aug 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)' !== '8/5/2013'
```

The solution will be to ensure we're comparing Date objects. Even that's tricky - if you're interested, there's lots of background discussion to read, starting with [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript) (including all the notes!). [This Blog](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/) covers the coercion topic clearly, but without details around dates.

That line of code above can be replaced with this, which will properly evaluate `true`. You could adopt one of the functions from the answer linked earlier, which would be more readable.

```
if (date - new Date('8/5/2013') == 0) {
```

Lather, rinse, repeat...